# Delete not done completely

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 2, jpa with hibernate.
I have an object with many child. I search to delete childs and child of child...

There is one relations who are not delete

I have theses objects.

```
public class Spi{
     ...

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "spi", orphanRemoval = true,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Asi> asi = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "spi", orphanRemoval = true,, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<SapI> sapI = new ArrayList<>();
    ..
}

public class Asi{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "asi", orphanRemoval = true,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Audited
    private List<Gi> gi = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    Spi spi;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "asi_scpi")
    private Set<Scpi> scpi = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Gi{
     ...
    @ManyToOne
    Asi asi;
}

public class Scpi{
    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "scpi")
    Set<Asi> asi = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Sapi{
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    Spi spi;
}
```

I search to keep Spi but to delete Asi and Sapi. Because I delete Asi, Scpi and gi should be delete too.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteChilds(Integer spiId){


    scpiRepository.deleteBySpiId(spiId);
    em.flush();
    em.clear();

    Optional<Spi> optSpi = repository.findById(spiId);

    if (optSpi.isPresent()) {

        Spi spi = optSpi.get();

        spi.getSpci().clear();
        spi.getAsi().clear();

        repository.save(spi);
    }
}
```

There is one relation who are not delete is the spci.
With

```
scpiRepository.deleteBySpiId(spiId);
```

I see there are two delete who are done one for the table and the join table, but that don't seem to be done

Comment: replacte your  cascade type with CascadeType.ALL or add  CascadeType.DELETE

Comment: cascade delete it's good for remove all child and parent... not good to put on manytomany... issue here like it's said it's the manty to many relation

Comment: how you checked is it deleted or not in same method or outside. If in same method your transaction may not be committed yet

Comment: @roberttrudel why do you ask your questions twice?

Comment: I you have terminate your primary school, you will see it's different... if you don't have answer to the question... go polluate another thread...